# What do they mean by the calling object?

Tags: java, object, methods

Write   a   class   MyInts.java with    the following   methods and constructors.

1- Array    of  int of  size    25  as  a   private field

2- Constructor  that    takes   a   string  of  integers    and stores  it  in  the array   of  int

3- A    Copy    constructor

4- A    method  Add that    takes   as  a   parameter   1   MyInt and   adds    it  to  the calling object  and returns the 
result.

5- A    method  isEqual that    checks  if  2   MyInt variables are equal.

6- A    method  compareTo that  returns -1  if  the calling object  is  less    than    the parameter,  +1  if  the 
calling object  is  greater than    the parameter   and 0   if  they    are equal

Anyone care to explain what the calling object means / is in the add method  ? Do they mean I should add the MyInt as paramater to another MyInt or what ?

Comment: The callee; the caller of the method.

Comment: It's very poor terminology. It is at best ambiguous. There is the calling *thread*, the calling *method*, but not the calling *object* in any useful sense, unless they mean the object on which the calling method was invoked, which isn't likely. What is meant is probably the object upon which the method is invoked, i.e. inside the called method, the object denoted by `this`. But you should ask whoever set the assignment. You may also tell them from me that there is no such thing as a copy constructor in Java.

Comment: @EJP It's perfectly sensible to talk about a "calling object"; it's the line one up in the stack trace, wherever the method invocation occurs.

Comment: @chrlylis There is no object in a stack trace line. There is a class and a line number. I've already provided a possible meaning of 'calling object', but I doubt that's what is meant in the assignment. To store something in the calling object, the method would have to be provided with that object as a callback, and it doesn't seem likely that these students are up to callbacks yet.

Answer (score 1):

Edit; given your comment ... we should be talking about the add method:

```
public MyInt {
   private final int[] numbers = new int[25];
 ... constructors, other methods

   public MyInt add(MyInt other) {
      for (int i=0; i < number.length; i++) {
        this.numbers[i] += other.numbers[i];
      }
      return this;
   }
```

*might* be the answer. The problem is that assignment 4 isnt really clear; as there is no "obvious" definition what **adding** two MyInt objects really means. It is also not at all clear what the result of that add operation can/should be.

Long story short: my implementation is *one* interpration of 4-A that assumes adding means: add the content of the other array into the first array; and then return that MyInt object that was "increased" (in that sense: the object on which the method was called). Maybe that is what you need; but to be sure;  you should ask your teacher for clarification.

Comment: I am refering to what add object refers to in the add method .

Answer (score 0):

As per GhodstCat's answer, there is another interpretation of the answer.

You can treat the `MyInt` objects as *immutable*, which means that once the object is created, its state does not get modified. Wikipedia has a great article on [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

This is what an immutable implementation of the answer could look like:

```
public MyInt {
    private final int[] numbers = new int[25];

    // Internal private constructor
    private MyInt(int[] numbers) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    public MyInt add(MyInt other) {
        int[] newNumbers = new int[25];

        for (int i=0; i < number.length; i++) {
            newNumbers [i] = numbers[i] + other.numbers[i];
        }

      return new MyInt(newNumbers);
   }
```

You will notice we do not modify the original objects `numbers` member, instead we create a new `MyInt` object which has the result of the addition.